# Carburettor Cleaner Additive? how good are they

Tags: fuel-system, cleaning, carburetor

I'm just wondering whether anyone has any experience with fuel additives that clean injectors and carburetors. I have an old motorcycle that starts, but can't keep it self running for long before it dies. It was left sitting over winter and I'm assuming the fuel lines and carbs are gummed up.

I don't want to attempt to take the carbs apart to have a go at cleaning them and balancing them etc since I'm afraid of ruining it ;)

Do these carb and fuel injector cleaning fuel additives actually work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These additives do work, but they do have a down side. You add it to the fuel and the fluid loosens and shifts the gumming up in the system. What can happen is they free up a lump of 'gum' which moves through the system until it blocks another part of the system. Not always, but when the system is badly 'gummed' a real possible. Best way to clean injectors is off of the vehicle on a made for purpose machine or replace them, carbs too are best done off of the vehicle.